# How to make div appear in front of another?

Tags: html, css

Please refer to the code below:

```
<ul>
 <li style="height:100px; overflow:hidden;">
  <div style="height:500px; background-color:black;">
  </div>
 </li>
</ul>
```

From the code above, we know that we can only see 100px height of  black background.

Hhow can we see 500px height of `<div>` black background? In other words, how can I make the `<div>` appear in front of `<li>`?

Comment: I don't know of any browser that would render only 100 pixels of height in your example.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5480656/2299235
the aroth's anweser worked for me :D (Y)

Comment: [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l55hSbBUdmQ) is extremely helpful to understand how it works.

Answer (score 156, accepted):

Use the CSS [z-index](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp) property.  Elements with a greater z-index value are positioned in front of elements with smaller z-index values.

Note that for this to work, you also need to set a `position` style (`position:absolute`, `position:relative`, or `position:fixed`) on both/all of the elements you want to order.

Comment: You may also want to remove any relevant `overflow:hidden` styling.

Comment: The you @AndyP This fixed my problem!.

Comment: Was struggling a lot to fix this with z-index. The above note on adding the `position` style fixed the issue in seconds

Answer (score 23):

In order an element to appear in front of another you have to give higher z-index to the front element, and lower z-index to the back element, also you should indicate `position: absolute/fixed...`

Example:

```
<div style="z-index:100; position: fixed;">Hello</div>
<div style="z-index: -1;">World</div>
```

Comment: This was what I needed cause I wanted to place a div over google maps.

Answer (score 20):

You can set the z-index in css

```
<div style="z-index: -1"></div>
```

Answer (score 6):

Upper div use higher z-index and lower div use lower z-index then use absolute/fixed/relative position

Answer (score 5):

The black `div` will display the full 500px unless `overflow:hidden` is set on the 100px `li`

Answer (score 1):

I think you're missing something.

http://jsfiddle.net/ZNtKj/

```
<ul>
 <li style="height:100px;overflow:hidden;">
  <div style="height:500px; background-color:black;">
  </div>
 </li>
</ul>
<ul>
 <li style="height:100px;">
  <div style="height:500px; background-color:red;">
  </div>
 </li>
</ul>
```

In FF4, this displays a 100px black bar, followed by a 500px red block.

A little bit different example:

http://jsfiddle.net/ZNtKj/1/

```
<ul>
 <li style="height:100px;overflow:hidden;">
  <div style="height:500px; background-color:black;">
  </div>
 </li>
</ul>
<ul>
 <li style="height:100px;">
  <div style="height:500px; background-color:red;">
  </div>
 </li>
 <li style="height:100px;overflow:hidden;">
  <div style="height:500px; background-color:blue;">
  </div>
 </li>
 <li style="height:100px;overflow:hidden;">
  <div style="height:500px; background-color:green;">
  </div>
 </li>
</ul>
```