# Fixed Positioned Element Getting behind Of Translucent Element

Tags: html, css

I have this elements:

```css
#first {background-color: red; position: fixed}
#second {background-color: green; opacity: 50%}
```

```html
<div id="first">first</div>
<div id="second">second</div>
```

but first element getting behind of second element.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make div appear in front of another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5480639/how-to-make-div-appear-in-front-of-another)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```css
#first {
  background-color: red;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 10;
}
```